# Ranking observations by percentile, based on subgroups?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with a column of data on company names, another column with the number of employees the company has, and another column that classifies the company by SIC code, like so:

```
Company    Employees     SIC Code
A              5          2011
B              10         2011
C              15         7374
D              11         7374
E              77         6733
F              44         6733
```

(This is just a simplified version; I several SIC codes, and thousands of company observations). Basically, what I want to do is classify companies according to their percentile rank by the number of employees they have, for each group of SIC codes. For example, for SIC code 2011, I would want to figure out which companies are above the 99th percentile for employees; the same for SIC code 6733 (and so on). Getting percentiles for observations by groups seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm having trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has powerful commands for manipulating data. There are functions underneath, but you can achieve a lot by just clicking the buttons in the Power Query window.

I had a go at this particular challenge and got it working. You can download and use my demo file from my OneDrive:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: Power Query demo - Percentile within Group.xlsx

As described on the ReadMe sheet, I only had to write 2 simple functions - the rest was built by clicking around the UI.